# В каком слое нужно реализовывать логику выбора источника данных (локальные данные или сеть)?

Tags: android, архитектура

В каких случаях Domain слой (бизнес-логика) может знать о существовании разных источников данных? Например, у меня есть такой код:

```
GetUserUseCase {

    UserRepository userRepository;

    GetUserUseCase(UserRepository userRepository) { 
       //... 
    }

    public Observble<User> getUser(int id) {
        return Observable.merge(userRepository.getLocal(id), userRepository.getRemote(id));
    }

}
```

т.е. мой репозиторий может отдавать данные из двух источников. Насколько это корректно с точки зрения "Чистой архитектуры"?

Это простой пример, у меня есть более сложные кейсы, когда мне необходимо точно знать из какого источника получены эти данные. Должен ли я пересмотреть свою архитектуру таким образом, чтобы `UseCase` не знал о разных источниках, т.е. у меня в репозитории был бы один метод `getUser()`, или это нормальная ситуация?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Зависит от *требований к приложению*, глобально есть два подхода:

1) **Умный репозиторий** Тогда это на уровне репозитория, а интерактор только просит данные. То есть бизнес логика без понятия откуда и как получены данные. А репозиторий управляет всеми кешами.

2) **Глупый репозиторий** Репозиторий только знает как достать и как сохранить данные, а интерактор сам говорит откуда и когда. А также именно интерактор решает когда сохранять, очищать данные и так далее

Обычно на практике более прост первый подход, так как пользователю и логике приложения не известно про локальные кеши и прочее.